# HP Pavilion laptop - Mapping the remote control?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, remote

Did some googling but didn't have any luck.  I have a Pavilion dv7 - it came with a nifty little remote control that has a button on it that will start up Windows Media Center.

My problem is that I don't want it to start up Media Center - I want it to start a different program.

Anyone know what I can do to take control of what the Remote does?

I'm running Windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and see if [GlovePIE](http://carl.kenner.googlepages.com/glovepie) will recognize the inputs from the remote. Using that program, you should be able to map any button press to another keyboard shortcut